# Easiest way to fast-foward branch

Tags: git, git-branch

```
$ git checkout branch-a
Switched to branch 'branch-a'
Your branch is behind 'origin/branch-a' by 3 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

**What's the easiest/fastest way to do what is suggested and fast-forward?**

I could do

```
$ git pull --ff-only # --ff-only for saftey
```

but that requires a connection to the upstream.

I could also do

```
$ git merge origin/branch-a
```

but that seems unnecessarily verbose, since git already knows what my tracking branch is.

---

EDIT: Justifaction of reasonableness: `git pull` doesn't need the upstream and the branch; it uses the defaults I have set. Seeing as how fast forwarding a branch is very common (so common that Git suggests/mentions it), it seems there would be a way to do this with defaults as well.

Comment: Do you mean fast in terms of keystrokes typed?

Comment: Yes. For example, `git pull` doesn't need `git pull origin branch-a`. It uses the upstream and tracking branch.

Comment: Are you aware of git aliases?

Comment: @merlin2011, yes. That is one possible answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `~/.gitconfig`.

```
[alias]
    ff = pull --ff-only
```

Now you can just do `git ff`.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

```
$ git config --global merge.defaultToUpstream true
```

Then

```
$ git merge
```

will merge the tracking branch (in my case, fast-forward to `origin/branch-a`).

(I'm not sure what the compelling use case is for having `merge.defaultToUpstream` be `false`.)